# Why can't print the row number in sheet 'DataSet'?

Tags: vba

I want to print the row number in sheet `DataSet` with `vba`:

```
Sub cal()
    Dim x As Integer
    Worksheets("DataSet").Activate
    x = ActiveSheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to "return a value" from VBA:

```
function cal()
    Dim x As Integer
    Worksheets("Dataset").Activate
    x = ActiveSheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row  
    cal = x   ' the value to return from this function.
End function
```

Then use it as in `=cal()`, i.e. same way as you would any other function in Excel.
Note though that the Workbook that contains it has to be open ( if it isn't the same Workbook[1] ).

[1] To call it from ANOTHER Workbook, include the workbook name (where it is!) in the call if so; `=WorkbookThatHasFunction!cal()` in Excel, `=WorkbookThatHasFunction.cal()` in LibreOffice.

Comment: *NOTE: From memory, not verified to be correct.*

Answer (score 0):

The information from `Debug.Print` is displayed on the Immediate window. If you want it displayed on your sheet, you need to select a range (B20 in the example below) and assign your result to it.

```vba
Sub cal()
    Dim x As Integer
    Worksheets("Dataset").Activate
    x = ActiveSheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row  
    ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Value = x   'Change this range to the appropriate cell where the result should be displayed.
    
End Sub
```